# Can not install Fedora OS 36

Tags: fedora, system-installation, distributions

I'm trying to install Fedora 36 using DroidDrive, but I encounter errors:

[image: Logs]

Partition table - mbr, there are no partitions on the disk, nvidia graphics card, the image is not damaged.

Comment: *the image is not damaged* - I'm not sure. The dbus service fails - it's kinda integral to Fedora.

Comment: the only thing is, during installation, the phone (the usb mass storage emulator) was disconnected from the computer with the image on its own

Comment: if this could affect the installation process, then how to fix it

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/